# Passing variable into a function that uses awk

Tags: function, variables, awk, parameter-passing, aix

I have a script that attempts to stop a certain process by name (but I need to specify a certain string that can't be killed, namely "notThisProcess"), then kills it after 20 seconds if it hasn't come down gracefully, ie:

```
#!/bin/ksh
bname=BTEST
bserver=BSERVER

PROCESS_ID=`ps auxww | awk '/PROCESS_NAME_ALPHA/ && !/awk/ && !/notThisProcess/ {print $2}'`
/apps/customapp/stopcommand -a $bname -processName PROCESS_NAME_ALPHA -serverName $bserver
sleep 20
kill -4 $PROCESS_ID

PROCESS_ID2=`ps auxww | awk '/PROCESS_NAME_BETA/ && !/awk/ && !/notThisProcess/ {print $2}'`
/apps/customapp/stopcommand -a $bname -processName PROCESS_NAME_BETA -serverName $bserver
sleep 20
kill -4 $PROCESS_ID2

#etc..
```

As my list of processes just increased I'm trying to put those steps into a function but I can't figure out how to pass the process name to awk.  ie, this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/ksh
bname=BTEST
bserver=BSERVER

cycleProcess()
{
PROCESS_ID=`ps auxww | awk '/$1/ && !/awk/ && !/notThisProcess/ {print $2}'`
/apps/customapp/stopcommand -a $bname -processName PROCESS_NAME_ALPHA -serverName $bserver
sleep 20
kill -4 $PROCESS_ID
}

cycleProcess PROCESS_NAME_ALPHA
cycleProcess PROCESS_NAME_BETA

exit
```

I've seen several references to assignment via -v but despite several attempts I haven't been successful.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
bname=BTEST
bserver=BSERVER

cycleProcess() {
    typeset procname="$1"
    typeset pid=$(ps auxww | awk -v name="$procname" '$0 ~ name && !/awk/ && !/notThisProcess/ {print $2}')
    if [[ -z "$pid" ]]; then
        echo "$procname is not running"
        return
    fi
    /apps/customapp/stopcommand -a "$bname" -processName "$procname" -serverName "$bserver"
    sleep 20
    kill -4 "$pid"
}

processes=(
    PROCESS_NAME_ALPHA
    PROCESS_NAME_BETA
)

for proc in "${processes[@]}"; do 
    cycleProcess "$proc"
done
```

`typeset` in a function is a way to declare a variable as local to that function.

I don't have access to an AIX box. `ps auxww` output on my Linux box shows the command name in field 11, so instead of `/name/ && !/awk/ && !/thisScript/` you might be able to use `$11 == name {print $2}`,
 or `$11 ~ name` if the match is not exact.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much it works great. One tiny typo on line 22 you have an extra }.  Oddly, it only ever affected the last process in the list of processes.  Thanks for an elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed. After the closing brace, the extra brace is just a regular character: `a=(1 2 3 4); echo "${a[@]}}"`

Answer (score 0):

you can pass them in a pipe char delimited list and compare with the last field.

```
ps ... | awk -v keep="process1|process2|process3"  '$NF!~keep{print $2}'
```

also note that in your script `awk '/$1/ && ...` the variable is not the bash variable but the first field passed to `awk` script.

Answer (score 0):

As others already noted, shell variables may be passed to awk scripts using the option **-v**. This must be used if the awk script resides in a seperate file (by using the option **-f**).

When specifying the awk script directly within the shell script between single quotes ('...'), You may also use the construct **' "** $*shell_variable* " '. Note that when doing so, there must be no spaces between the single and double quotes!

Example:

```
process_string="plugin-container"

pids=$( ps -fu $LOGNAME | awk '/'"$process_string"'/ { print $2 }' )
```